# Sql Update Error

Tags: php, html, sql

My site's panel.php page shows users account information. The page shows data in inputs and users can update but there is a error when they click update button.

I took this error;

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '(fname, lname, mail, password, country, sex, facebook, twitter,
>   instagram, snapc' at line 1

Panel.php

```
<form action="panelpost.php" method="post">
First name: <input type="text" name="fname" value="<?php echo $row1['fname']; ?>"><br>
Last name: <input type="text" name="lname" value="<?php echo $row1['lname']; ?>"><br>
Mail: <input type="text" name="mail" value="<?php echo $row1['mail']; ?>"><br>
Password: <input type="text" name="password" value="<?php echo $row1['password']; ?>"><br>
Country: <input type="text" name="country" value="<?php echo $row1['country']; ?>"><br>
Sex: <input type="text" name="sex" value="<?php echo $row1['sex']; ?>"><br>
Facebook: <input type="text" name="facebook" value="<?php echo $row1['facebook']; ?>"><br>
Twitter: <input type="text" name="twitter" value="<?php echo $row1['twitter']; ?>"><br>
Instagram: <input type="text" name="instagram" value="<?php echo $row1['instagram']; ?>"><br>
Whatsapp: <input type="text" name="whatsapp" value="<?php echo $row1['snapchat']; ?>"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Update">
</form>
```

panelpost.php

```
<?php

include('connect.php');
session_start();

    $baslik = $_POST["fname"];
    $icerik = $_POST["lname"];
    $footer = $_POST["mail"];
    $baslik1 = $_POST["password"];
    $icerik1 = $_POST["country"];
    $footer1 = $_POST["sex"];
    $baslik2 = $_POST["facebook"];
    $icerik2 = $_POST["twitter"];
    $footer2 = $_POST["instagram"];
    $baslik3 = $_POST["snapchat"];

    $sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE uyeler SET (fname, lname, mail, password, country, sex, facebook, twitter, instagram, snapchat) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) WHERE mail ='{$_SESSION['kullanici']}'");
    $ekle = $sql->execute(array(

        $baslik,
        $icerik,
        $footer,
        $baslik1,
        $icerik1,
        $footer1,
        $baslik2,
        $icerik2,
        $footer2,
        $baslik3,

        ));

    $hata = $sql->errorInfo();
    echo empty($hata[2]) ?  "Başarılı Bir Şekilde Çalıştı." : $hata[2];

?>
```

Comment: remove the `SET` from the query and check.

Comment: I removed but error still continue. i take same error

Comment: `SET` is required for `UPDATE` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: doh, mixing update and insert sorry

Comment: Should be like this `UPDATE uyeler SET fname = ?, ... WHERE mail ='{$_SESSION['kullanici']}'` as noted you're mixing up the insert syntax with the update syntax. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @Can please up-vote the answer also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your query like below:-

```
$sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE uyeler SET fname=?, lname=?, mail=?, password=?, country=?, sex=?, facebook=?, twitter=?, instagram=?, snapchat=? WHERE mail ='{$_SESSION['kullanici']}'");
```

Note:- it will be better if you `parameterized`. your last  `SESSION` value also in the same way.

Comment: thank you very much:) . These are fixed :)

Comment: The SESSION value should also be parameterized.

Comment: I just added the comment. and thanks for acceptance.

Answer (score 0):

Your `UPDATE` query is incorrect. You have to explicitly assign value for each column

```
$sql = $db->prepare("UPDATE uyeler SET fname = ?, lname = ?, ... WHERE mail ='{$_SESSION['kullanici']}'");
```

Comment: is it correct having `....` in code?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh I'm just being lazy. I'm sure he can figured it out

Comment: But atleast you need to give clean and clear code. It's not about laziness. thanks.